# Table filter: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a filter for my table and I'm using the code below but I keep getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

I know that this has been asked before but it doesn't work for me.

I've tried this myself:

```
var rex = new RegExp($(this).val().toLowerCase(), 'i');
```

But I'm still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#filter', function(event) {
            filter();
        });

      function filter() {
        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.searchable tr').hide();
        $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }) .show();
    }
```

The filter I'm using and where it's working but when I use that one I don't get any errors and when I fill in something nothing happens: 
http://jsfiddle.net/giorgitbs/52aK9/1/

My code:
http://jsfiddle.net/52aK9/787/

Thanks!

Comment: I think $(this).val() could be null

Comment: Create a fiddle of your code showing your problem

Comment: `this` in filter seem to be `window`,  try passing the `this` in the keyup callback to your filter function as argument, `filter(this)`

Comment: Updated my post with a fiddle showing my problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arkhipov/52aK9/789/